# How to end a Powerpoint slideshow while staying on the current/active slide?

Tags: vba, powerpoint, shortcut

I'm looking for the opposite of the "Alt+F5" shortcut (Start a presentation from the current slide) as I have a very large presentation with many slides and want to be able to edit them quickly.

Currently, the "end show" action button I've set-upped (or the "ESC" shortcut) brings me back to my first slide.

I've managed to assign the following macro to a "stop" button, but this asks me to have as many lines as there are slides.

```
Sub ExitSlide3()

Application.SlideShowWindows(1).View.Exit

With Application.ActiveWindow

.ViewType = ppViewSlide

.View.GotoSlide 3

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **Insert>Action>Run macro**, assign this to a shape, then copy the shape to each slide. The shape can be the same color as the background if you want it to be unobstrusive:

```
Sub ExitSlide()
    ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Exit
End Sub
```

Comment: Dear John, thank you for answering my question ! This macro also returns to the first slide in a similar fashion to the "End Show" action. it is important to note that when I run the macro in the "Visual Basic for Applications project" window, I get the following message : run-time error ' -2147188160 (80048240)': Presentation (unknown member): "invalid request. there is currently no slide show view for this presentation"... Any ideas ?

Comment: I test all code before posting. The _ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Exit_ statement ends the slide show and returns to Edit mode at the slide that was currently selected in the slide show. 

If your installation is doing something different, it may be time for an Office repair: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b

The error message you're getting in the VBE should be self-explanatory. The statement ends a slideshow, but you not running a slideshow. So you get an error.

Comment: Dear John, thank you once again for replying : I tweaked around some settings in Powerpoint and it turns out that as long as the Show type is defined as "Browsed by an individual window" then the macro gets me back to the first slide. With the show type defined as "Presented by a speaker full screen" the ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Exit statement works like a charm.